# Оптимально записать много адресо файлов в каталоге в массив

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
<?
$sea = "jpg"; // ищем файлы только с таким расширением
$dir = './'; // ищем файлы в данном каталоге
$dh = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    if($filename != "." AND $filename != "..") { // убираем каталог вверх и текущий
        $filename_ex = explode(".",$filename);
        $filename_ex_co = count($filename_ex);
        if($filename_ex_co > 1) { // убираем файлы без расширения
            $filename_ex_co_m1 = $filename_ex_co - 1;
            if ($filename_ex[$filename_ex_co_m1] == $sea) { // оставляем только файлы с расширением $sea
                $files[] = $filename;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Данный код загоняет в массив названия файлов с расширением jpg. Есть пару вопросов, и охота задать их в одной теме, а не плодить много разных под разными никами )

теория:
 1. Каков предел добавления позиций в массив? (допустим мне нужно 50к)
 2. Аналогичный вопрос про массив в сессии. Получится? Влезет? // $_SESSION['files'][] = $filename;

код:
 3. Может ли кто написать, является ил этот метод более менее производительным (т.к. сам только только изучаю работу с каталогом) ? Есть ли еще способы более быстрые? (т.к. объем у меня не маленький)

Comment: $files = glob("$dir/*.jpg"); // если нет каталогов с именами типа blabla.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = glob($dir.'/*.jpg');
```

[Glob на](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) [php.net](http://php.net)